# ¿Cómo saber si mi aplicación lanza peticiones en background?

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenos días,

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe si existe una herramienta en Android Studio u otra que me ayude a verificar si mi aplicación esta lanzando peticiones en background a un servidor,

De antemano gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: utiliza `Logs` o depuración en el segmento que quieres verificar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso del `LogCat` puede ayudar ya que imprime eventos del sistema pero puede no detectar peticiones de aplicaciones instaladas, a menos que tengan programado específicamente el escribir en el Log cuando se realiza la petición.

Existen aplicaciones que detectan peticiones desde el dispositivo como:

[Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes revisar también las aplicaciones similares a esta en Google PlayStore, no puedo recomendarte otra porque no las he usado a excepción de esta.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ¿Como puedo filtrar para que solo me muestre las peticiones de una sola aplicación?

Comment: Hola Leo, esta aplicación despliega todas las peticiones, puedes distinguirlas por el nombre de aplicación, no estoy seguro si en la última versión puedes aplicar un filtro por nombre de aplicación.

Comment: sabes si Network Statistics del Android monitor almacena el monitoreo de red en algun lugar,  solo veo que marca los picos pero no se si los guarda

Comment: Hola Leo, en realidad no creo que se guarden, sinceramente lo desconozco, pero para modo de pruebas puedes guardar un imágenes del comportamiento en la linea de tiempo, y posteriormente realizar comparaciones..